# Getting ActiveX component cant create object while trying to connect to ALM through VB macro

Tags: excel, alm, vba

Getting ActiveX component cant create object error While debuuging the line - 
 Set QCConn = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")

Comment: In order to use OTA, you gotta install 'HP ALM Connectivity' add-in

Answer (score 1):

You must be using 64 Bit Excel.

When ALM try to create OTA object(32 bit dll) in a 64 bit excel you will be produced with this error.

Try the same code in 32 Bit Excel it will work smooth.

Note : Please register both Clint and Site admin registration and dont forget to add the References.